# C# with SQL Server Application Roles: Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm attempting to implement an Application Role with my connections in a C# Winforms Desktop application.  Everything works fine with the first connection, and I am closing it properly with a using{} construct.  However, when I create a second connection, I get the "Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state" error.  Any idea as to why I'm getting this error and how to troubleshoot?  Here is my code where I get the error along with my method to set the application role:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        oAppRole.setApplicationRole(connection);

        string query = "<sql statement here>";

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", empID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpDate", priorExpDate);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dtReturnTable);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

---

```
public bool setApplicationRole(SqlConnection connection)
{
    bool retVal = true;
    string procName = "sys.sp_setapprole";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    // Parameter for Application Role Name
    SqlParameter parmAppRoleName = new SqlParameter();
    parmAppRoleName.ParameterName = "@rolename";
    parmAppRoleName.Value = "myAppRole";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parmAppRoleName);

    // Parameter for Application Role Password
    SqlParameter parmAppRolePwd = new SqlParameter();
    parmAppRolePwd.ParameterName = "@password";
    parmAppRolePwd.Value = "myPassword";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parmAppRolePwd);

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        retVal = false;
        throw(ex);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Slight detour...https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Check [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4163478/fix-access-violation-when-incremental-statistics-automatically-updated) for some ideas. Second, are you trying to modify the role of the user you are connected with? I assume you do not receive this error when you perform other, non application role updates?

Comment: @JacobH, We aren't using partitioning, so the link doesn't help any, but thanks.  I'm not sure what you mean by "non application role updates," but let me say this is a working application where I'm trying to introduce application roles (ie, the application works fine before I added code for using an application role).

Comment: And if you set the application role through SSMS instead, do you get the same error? What if you use a different account (sa?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Application Roles are rarely the right security approach.  They are designed to work in combination with End Users connecting with Windows Integrated Authentication as low-privilege users.  This enables the Application code to use a semi-secret password to elevate the session from the end-user's identity to the Application Role.  This is really a desktop, client/server app solution.  And as such it never really played nicely with Connection Pooling.

When a Connection Pool attempts to reset a connection which has had an Application Role set, an error is thrown.  So to get Application Roles to work with SqlConnection you either have to disable Connection Pooling (on by default in all applications, but can be disabled in the connection string), or [sp_unsetapprole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-unsetapprole-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) before returning the connection to the pool.

For alternative approaches see [Application Role Alternatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/creating-application-roles-in-sql-server#application-role-alternatives).

Comment: FYI, this *is* a desktop, client/server app, and I have edited the question to specifically state that.

Comment: Cool.  In a desktop application you can sometimes just scope your SqlConnection to a form or view model and disable connection pooling, if you don't want to `unset` the app role before closing the connection.

Comment: I'm not following how to disable connection pooling in a desktop application.  I thought that was only for web apps and google search seems to confirm that.

Comment: Connection Pooling is on by default for SqlConnection in all applications.  Just set `pooling=false` in the connection string to disable pooling.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8